# Programmatic way to delete users from Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my application I want to be able to programmatically create and delete user accounts in Azure Active Directory. This program needs to run unattended.

I am able to [create](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users) Azure AD users but keep getting failures when [deleting](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_delete) a user account. Specifically, I am getting the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 
    Code: Authorization_RequestDenied 
    Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I think this is by design because the documentation states that only delegated permissions are supported. Can someone from MS Graph team confirm that it is not possible to delete AD users in unattended fashion (e.g. without prompting for admin user account and password)? Is this functionality going to be supported in the future?

Are there different ways to solve this problem? Would the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) work for this (even though it is not recommended to use now)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, `DELETE /users/{id}` requires `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` which is only available for delegated scenarios.

This is unlikely to change given the security exposure this would introduce. A rogue application creating users would certainly be extremely annoying, but a rogue application *deleting* users would be outright catastrophic.

My suggestion would be to have your application maintain a "deletion queue". Whenever you need to delete a user, simply add that `id` to the queue. Then provide an interactive experience for Admins that allows them to login and delete the queued users after reviewing the list.